# Spring Boot : How to get program args with ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to get some properties from the command line when I start my app. I really try a lot of solution but nothings is working. I'll only use **@Value** as a last solution

```
java -jar myjar.jar --test.property=something
```

Here's some classes

> Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(TestApplication.class);
        builder.run(args);
    }
}
```

> Config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(StringProperties.class)
public class StringConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private StringProperties stringProperties;

    @Bean(name = "customBeanName")
    public List<String> properties() {
        List<String> properties = new ArrayList<>();

        properties.add(stringProperties.getString());

        return properties;
    }
}
```

> Properties class

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("test")
public class StringProperties {

    private String property;

    public String getString() {
        return property;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ops.....I have tested your code.It is setProperty that missed in StringProperties.

```
 public void setProperty(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }
```